# Oracle Continuous Query Notification encryption

Tags: oracle, encryption, jdbc, change-notification, continuous-query-notification

Is there a way to configure Oracle [Continuous Query Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/continuos-query-notification.html) sent from the server to the registered client, to be encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it.  But I would expect that if you [configured the underlying JDBC connection to use SSL encryption](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc-tlsv12-jks-or-oracle-wallets-122-and-lower) the CQN notifications would be encrypted in transit.